# How do I add other directories to sync over Onedrive in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive

When activating the sync feature of Windows 10/Onedrive one is asked which of the three directories Desktop, Documents and Pictures should be synced between devices.

How do I add other directories to this list, like Videos or Downloads or misc?

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive has the particularity that it will only sync files from its folder,
located at `%UserProfile%\OneDrive`.

Nevertheless, you may trick it to think that your other folders are contained
as subfolders using symbolic links.

To sync any folder to OneDrive, open a Command Prompt and enter this command:

```
mklink /j "%UserProfile%\OneDrive\Folder-Name" "Full path of source folder"
```

The source folder will now appear in OneDrive under the name of "Folder-Name"
and be synced automatically.